# Replacing null values with 0 after spark dataframe left outer join

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes called *left* and *right*.

```
scala> left.printSchema
root
|-- user_uid: double (nullable = true)
|-- labelVal: double (nullable = true)
|-- probability_score: double (nullable = true)

scala> right.printSchema
root
|-- user_uid: double (nullable = false)
|-- real_labelVal: double (nullable = false)
```

Then, I join them to get the joined Dataframe. It is a ***left outer join***. Anyone interested in the natjoin function can find it here.

> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f02bd79528ac75f57ae8

```
scala> val joinedData = natjoin(predictionDataFrame, labeledObservedDataFrame, "left_outer")

scala> joinedData.printSchema
|-- user_uid: double (nullable = true)
|-- labelVal: double (nullable = true)
|-- probability_score: double (nullable = true)
|-- real_labelVal: double (nullable = false)
```

Since it is a left outer join, the real_labelVal column has nulls when user_uid is not present in right.

```
scala> val realLabelVal = joinedData.select("real_labelval").distinct.collect
realLabelVal: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([0.0], [null])
```

**I want to replace the null values in the realLabelVal column with 1.0.**

Currently I do the following:

1. I find the index of real_labelval column and use the spark.sql.Row API to set the nulls to 1.0.
   (This gives me a RDD[Row])
2. Then I apply the schema of the joined dataframe to get the cleaned dataframe.

The code is as follows:

```
 val real_labelval_index = 3
 def replaceNull(row: Row) = {
    val rowArray = row.toSeq.toArray
     rowArray(real_labelval_index) = 1.0
     Row.fromSeq(rowArray)
 }

 val cleanRowRDD = joinedData.map(row => if (row.isNullAt(real_labelval_index)) replaceNull(row) else row)
 val cleanJoined = sqlContext.createDataFrame(cleanRowRdd, joinedData.schema)
```

**Is there an elegant or efficient way to do this?**

Goolging hasn't helped much. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does nat stand for in natjoin?

Comment: @JosiahYoder nat stands for Natural Join.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried using `na`

```
joinedData.na.fill(1.0, Seq("real_labelval"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is we use cloudera distribution and the cluster has spark 1.3.0. The fill functions were introduced in spark 1.4 I think. I am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Do I need to import anything to use na? Thanks

Comment: @GavinNiu No, `na` is a method directly on `DataFrame`

Comment: What is Seq() doing?

Comment: `fill` takes an array (Seq), thus the wrapper.

Comment: This fills all the nulls, not just the ones that are caused by the join.